# How to forward request coming from skype bot webhook to node server

Tags: node.js, apache, iptables, skypedeveloper, microsoft-skype-bot

on my server both apache and node server is running.
Apache used for few other application, If i used ngrok webhook then getting call from skype bot to server but if i changed webhook to my actual https://example.com/skbot then its not working, even i am not getting any call from skype bot to my server.

I stopped apache sever and tried same thing then its working for me with ssl certificate.

Can we do somthing using iptables rules ??? or any other solution available for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried so many things and finally its working for me with virtual host. With ProxyPass we can forward request coming from skype bot on default port to node server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPass /bot http://localhost:8088
</VirtualHost>
```